# Many to many relation with join is returnin an entity that I don't have

Tags: java, hibernate

I've a table Computer and a table Employee with relation many to many.

In the DB I have a linking table but in Hibernate I have just the entities for two tables Computer and Employee.

I want to return a list of employee that can use a particular computer, so I'm doing:

```
String queryString = "from Employee h join h.computer u where u.id = :computer_id";
Query queryObject = getSession().createQuery(queryString);
queryObject.setInteger("computer_id", id);
return queryObject.list();
```

The problem of the previous code is that it's returning a list of an entity that I don't have. I should have List<ComputerEmployee> but I don't have and I don't want this. I want a List<Employee>.

So when I try to read the properties from any other of the previous list I get this error:

```
Bean property 'id' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?: org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'id' of bean class [[Ljava.lang.Object;]: Bean property 'id' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
```

So, how should I reformulate the HQL query in order to get a valid `List<Employee>`?

**Update:**

In debug I checked the list in that way:

`list.get(0).getClass()`

It returns `java.lang.Object`

The conf is in the session factory bean of spring, in that way:

`<property name="packagesToScan" value="uk.co.bau.domain"></property>`

This is the top part:

```
@Entity
public class Employee implements Serializable {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String name;
```

Comment: Does your Entity `Employee` have an id attribute defined?

Comment: yes, the fact is that it looks like it's not returning a list of employee. It's returning something else that appears more like a list of Object.

Comment: Odd.  Can you post your hibernate configuration for that class? If you're using annotations, also post the top portion of the class where your fields and class annotations are located

Comment: That is odd.  Try explicitly adding an `@Table(name="Employee")` tag, and explicitly annotating `name` and any other fields.

Comment: Does your `Employee` has an attribute `computer` mapped to another entity that has an `id` attribute?

Comment: Employee has the attribute computer and computer has the attribute Employee. Each one has an attribute id.

Comment: Looking at the error message, it seems that one of the entities have a `getId()` that returns `Object`, is that right?